# how to capture the value of a gridview template field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

In the RowDataBound event of an ASP.NET Gridview I am trying to read the value of a Label in a Template Field. I would prefer to capture this value in the RowUpdating Event, but for some reason I seem to recall that it is not possible. Here is the ASP...

```
<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Translation" ItemStyle-Width="250" >                      
    <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lang_String") %>' Width="250px"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Here is the VB.net code that I am trying to figure out....

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If (e.Row.RowState And DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0 Then
        ' The value in the third column postion.
        Dim needThisValue as string = e.Row.Cells(3).Text

    End If
End Sub
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think that your Label is in the `EditItemTemplate` because you've chosen `RowState=DataControlRowState.Edit`.

Actually you neeed to check for `RowType=DataControlRowType.DataRow`. That is required since the first row's `RowType` is the Header.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        ' in the following way you get the row's DataSource: '
        Dim row = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row
        ' you could also use the DataSource to get the value: '
        Dim lang_String = row.Field(Of String)("lang_String")
        ' and here you get the reference to your Label in the ItemTemplate: '
        Dim Label11 = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("Label11"), Label)
        ' at this point Label11.Text is already set to lang_String '
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to get the controls of your `EditItemTemplate` you need to check aditionally the [RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowstate.aspx), for example in your GridView(normally you would use an editable control like TextBox in `EditItemTemplate`):

```
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="LblLanguage" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lang_String") %>' Width="250px"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtLanguage" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lang_String") %>' Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

in `RowDataBound`:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        ' in the following way you get the row's DataSource: '
        Dim row = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row
        ' you could also use the DataSource to get the value: '
        Dim lang_String = row.Field(Of String)("lang_String")

        If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Normal Then
            ' and here you get the reference to your Label in the ItemTemplate: '
            Dim LblLanguage = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("LblLanguage"), Label)
            ' at this point LblLanguage.Text is already set to lang_String '
        ElseIf e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit Then
            ' and here you get the reference to your TextBox in the EditItemTemplate: '
            Dim TxtLanguage = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("TxtLanguage"), TextBox)
            ' at this point TxtLanguage.Text is already set to lang_String '
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that i've changed the ID of the controls to somewhat more readable.

Comment: Well, I need to be certain that the row selected was in Edit Mode. Since the Header Row never will be... Works in other sections, I'll have to review them to see if they require change. thanks for the snippet, I'll test now. Yea this is NOT for a recursive loop. Only need the value for the row being edited.

Comment: @marc11h: Edited my answer. In RowUpdating you need `Dim row = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)` to get the updating row in the grid. Then you can also use `FindControl` to get the reference to your conrol.

Comment: I do have the Texbox in the Edit Template, the issue was that I couldn't seem to capture the Label value (original value, your LblLanguage) when I went into edit mode during the RowUpdating Event. I was hoping to capture the origValue in RowUpdating event to avoid using a session variable to pass the origValue from the RowDataBound Event to the RowUpdating Event where I update the DB. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @marc11h: I'm not sure. Why do you need to "pass" something from RowDataBound to RowUpdating? Both have completely different purposes. The first is triggered when you've set the Grid's DataSource and called DataBind, the latter is called when the user has clicked the update-button(not the edit-button) after he has changed something. If anything, then RowDataBound is called **after** RowUpdating since you have to DataBind the GridView again after you've commited the new values to dbms.

Comment: my concern was being able to capture the original value in the RowUpdating Event. I could never seem to find the Label control in ItemTemplate from within RowUpdating event. So I went back to RowDataBound event to catch it then assign to session so I can use it in the RowUpdating event as I save the previous value of that column when it changes for roll back purposes.